# APT error: Malformed entry 1 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/itchio.list

Tags: apt, updates, software-sources

[image: Not sure what to do from here.]

I really don't care if I get rid of the update or get it I just want this annoying red dot gone. I know that I can not show notifications but I want them.

I did what the notification told me to do but I was unable to remove or update the file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Modified question title to show what looks like the relevant part.

This looks like a result of something that "itch.io" installed.

Comment: How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @bwebb33, remove that file using `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/itchio.list; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get -f install`

Answer (score 2):

According to the error message, the problem is caused by something in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/itchio.list`

I'm assuming this is part of itch.io.  You have a few options:

- Remove itch.io using the appropriate method for doing so.  If this involves removing a package, you may need to *purge* the package rather than just removing it.
- Edit the above file to identify where the problem is (it's in the first entry) and try and fix it.
- Contact the makers of itch.io for help with the problem.